# Prevent editors from downloading the file

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently working on a google sheet.

There are two tabs, one is a master sheet and the other one is a table that allow the user to input the product name and the sales price will show up.
However, I don't want the user to see the master sheet. Even though I hide the master sheet, the user is able to unhide it if they download the sheet.
Is it possible to

1. Disable the download option for the editor?

OR

2. Reference the master list without including it in the same file?

OR

3. Hide the master list even the user download the file?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the editor access to print the file cannot be disable (tried and tested using this [guide](https://venturebeat.com/2015/07/14/you-can-now-disable-downloading-printing-and-copying-for-any-file-stored-in-google-drive/)). I would suggest creating a file (master) and a dependent file which users can download. You can also create a script that will copy the content of the master file to the dependent file. Then only limit the master file access to yourself.

Here is a code snippet that will copy the master file to your public file:

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];

 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_GOES HERE");

 sheet.copyTo(destination);
```

Hope this helps.